# Difference between function inside directive VS function inside controller

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS newb here, with a lot of questions.

1. May I ask what's exactly the difference between a function written inside a directive from one written inside a controller?

For example, in this directive snippet:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.hideModal = function () { 
                    console.log("hide modal fxn called");
                    scope.show = false;
                };
            },
template:'<div class=\"ng-modal\" ng-show=\"$scope.show\">' + 
            '<div class=\"ngdialog-overlay\" ng-click=\"hideModal()\"></div>' +
            '<div class=\"ng-modal-dialog\" ng-style=\"dialogStyle\">' + 
              '<div class=\"ng-modal-close\" ng-click=\"hideModal()\">X</div>' + 
              '<div class=\"ng-modal-dialog-content\" ng-transclude></div>' + 
              '<div style=\"left:80%\"><button type = \"button\" style=\"float:right\">Next</button></div>' +
            '</div>' + 
         '</div>'
```

2. Why's the hideModal() function written inside link (not sure what this is called) instead of inside a controller?
3. Is it possible to write hideModal() inside a controller?
4. If the answer to #3 is yes, can I omit writing link altogether? Will there be any disadvantages if I do this?

I'm asking these because I can't get the hideModal() function to work no matter where I put it (either directive or in controller), and I want to understand why.

I'd appreciate it very much if you can answer me in layman's terms as much as possible. AngularJS is being such a pain to understand for me and I'm not that well-versed in it yet, so there's a 100% chance that you'll get blank stares from me if you do otherwise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is really no difference if it's added to the `$scope`. The `scope` in the `link` function is exactly the same as the `$scope` you would `$inject` in your controller.
2. Not sure why it's in the `link` function. I only use `link` if I need DOM manipulation, i.e. through jQuery
3. Yes, this is perfectly fine because it's added to the same `$scope`.
4. There will be no disadvantages, you can for sure ommit the `link` function entirely.

---

the general rule is, do you need `DOM` manipulation? Use the `link` function otherwise just stick with `controller`.

The difference is in execution time, `controller` function is executed before compilation while `link` is executed after the template compilation.

That's why you would use the link function for `DOM` manipulation. During the `controller` phase the template is not yet compiled, thus you can't use `DOM` manipulation inside the constructor of your function.

---

And if you don't need `DOM` manipulation at all, it might be better to look at the new `.component` syntax. This is much easier to understand compared to the `.directive` syntax. Keep in mind the `.component` syntax is just limited abstraction of `.directive`

[Link to the component docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the additional info about .component. :) Hoping I could find a chance to use it in my current project. Just to confirm, I can use this exactly the same as a directive, correct?

Comment: Not exactly, see the link to the docs and take a look at the comparison table. But in general, if you're using a component architecture it will be possible to replace many directives with components. The idea is the same, component is a simplistic form of a directive. `.component` is available since angular 1.5

Comment: I see. Will definitely look into this. Thank you!